# add new sheet on existing excel document and add DataGridView content to the sheet using visual basic

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

Currently the code creates a new excel file named whatever I put in the textbox87 I need it to just add a new sheet to the file but also want to choose which sheet it must save to.

I basically want to create a excel sheet 
then copy `DataGridView` as is to that excel sheet
but also want to copy new data from the `DataGridView` to the same excel document but to another sheet
currently its just overwriting the current document and not adding sheets.

```
\\\

            Dim sheetIndex As Integer
            Dim Ex As Object
            Dim Wb As Object
            Dim Ws As Object
            Dim thefilesnamet As String = TextBox87.Text
            Ex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            Wb = Ex.workbooks.add

            ' Copy each DataTable as a new Sheet

            'On Error Resume Next
            Dim col, row As Integer
            ' Copy the DataTable to an object array
            Dim rawData(DataGridView5.Rows.Count, DataGridView5.Columns.Count - 1) As Object

            ' Copy the column names to the first row of the object array

            For col = 0 To DataGridView5.Columns.Count - 1
                rawData(0, col) = DataGridView5.Columns(col).HeaderText.ToUpper

            Next

            For col = 0 To 
    5.Columns.Count - 1
                For row = 0 To DataGridView5.Rows.Count - 1
                    rawData(row + 1, col) = DataGridView5.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value

                Next
            Next
            ' Calculate the final column letter
            Dim finalColLetter As String = String.Empty
            finalColLetter = ExcelColName(DataGridView5.Columns.Count) 'Generate Excel Column Name (Column ID)


            sheetIndex += 1
            Ws = Wb.Worksheets(sheetIndex)
            'MessageBox.Show(Ws)
            'Ws.name = "Test10"
            Dim excelRange As String = String.Format("A1:{0}{1}", finalColLetter, DataGridView5.Rows.Count + 1)

            Ws.Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData
            Ws = Nothing
            Dim wheretosavethis As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "/dealsforafricafiles/" & thefilesnamet & ".xlsx"

            Wb.SaveAs(wheretosavethis, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
            Wb.Close(True, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
            Wb = Nothing
            ' Release the Application object
            Ex.Quit()
            Ex = Nothing
            ' Collect the unreferenced objects
            GC.Collect()
            MsgBox("Exported Successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

\\\
```

Comment: The posted code appears to create a “new” workbook with the line… `Wb = Ex.workbooks.add` … then later in the code the workbook is “saved.” Currently this will overwrite the file if it exists. Thereby removing any previously saved data in that file. It is unclear whether you want to overwrite the existing file or not.

Comment: In addition, when the code references a “worksheet” using the variable `sheetIndex`… it is always going to be the “same” worksheet… in this case worksheet 1. The variable `sheetIndex` is created “new” in the code and will always be one (1). If you want to “create” a “new” worksheet in the workbook every time the code runs, then the code is going to have to “add” a new worksheet. Simply incrementing an index will not work since the workbook may not have that many worksheets. Therefore to “add” a new worksheet the code may look something like… `Ws = Wb.Worksheets.Add()`

Comment: Lastly, I highly recommend you check to make sure that the code is “releasing” the COM objects it creates. Namely the application and the workbook. I do not think the code …`Ex.Quit()`, `Ex = Nothing` and `GC.Collect` is going to properly “release” the COM objects the code creates. This is going to end up “leaking” resources which can be seen in the Task Manager under the background processes. I suggest a `using` statement when opening the app and workbook and finally calling `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Ex)`. In my test the posted code leaves these resources open.